# Sonata admin configureFormFields add action

Tags: sonata-admin

How i can add custom action to configureFormFields Admin

```
class ContractAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
    ///here
   }
}
```

I try add action to this menu

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom admin action you add add according to the [manual](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html). What are you writing about is form fields for add / edit action.

For the buttons, you need to override method `getActionButtons`

```
public function getActionButtons($action, $object = null)
{
    $actions = parent::getActionButtons($action, $object);
    if ($action == 'edit') {
        $actions['myKey'] = ['template' => 'template_path_to_render.html.twig'];
    }
    return $actions;
}
```